# Local video files won't play in Cordova Android App

Tags: android, html, video, cordova

I'm building an app in Cordova where the first page of the app contains a video tag set to autoplay. I don't get any 404 errors loading the file... The file just won't play. The video is just black with a 0:00 time length that doesn't change.

The strange thing is I get two network requests in Chrome remote dev tools for the video file: the first shows a (success) status, and the second has a status of (cancelled). I've tried using two different URLs for the file:

file:///android_asset/www/video/nameofmyvideo.mp4 with the video file actually in /www/video/nameofmyvideo.mp4.

and

android.resource://mypackagename/raw/nameofmyvideo with the video file actually in /www/res/raw/nameofmyvideo and /platforms/android/res/raw/nameofmyvideo

I'm running the latest cordova (3.4.1-0.1.0) and testing on a kindle fire running CM-11 (4.4.2).

Here's the the markup I'm using:

```
<video width="400px" height="300px" autoplay controls>
    <source src="file:///android_asset/www/video/video-test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

OR

```
<video width="400px" height="300px" autoplay controls>
    <source src="android.resource://my.package.name/raw/videotest" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Is this an android pathing issue? The app runs fine as-is in iOS. I've also tried using webm, with no success.

edit:

Also it seems that the double network load issue (one success, one cancelled) happens regardless of whether the file can actually load. I loaded the same mp4 file over http hosted on my website and the video played fine (but still showed both requests).

Comment: What if remove px, as I mentioned?

Comment: Sadly, no. I've tried without px, with percentages, and without explicit width or height. Still no luck.

Comment: From everything I can tell, this appears to be a file permission issue. Remote URLs over HTTP work fine, and plugins that use the android.resource URL to move and access the video file locally return 404s. Am I missing something in my config.xml potentially?

Answer (score 2):

Its **not possible to read video from inside assets** folder on android, you need to place it somewhere outside app, sdcard or remotely.
That's because APK is compressed JAR basically and files in assets needs to be decompressed to work, and Android can't decompress video files from APK.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. I have an Angular application, in the assets folder I have a video I use as a screensaver and loaded with the video tag. I wrapped the app in Cordova. It's deployed to large 32" Android kiosks in gas stations across the southeast. Loads fine. I am currently seeing an issue where it will randomly stop playing, which is why I landed on this post.

Answer (score 1):

well in case somebody needs it, you may embed below code. I've tried it and it works both in android and ios.

```
<object CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="100%" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
                                <param name="src" value="{{filename}}">
                                <param name="qtsrc" value="{{filename}}">
                                <param name="autoplay" value="false">
                                <param name="loop" value="false">
                                <param name="controller" value="true">
                                <embed src="{{filename}}" qtsrc="{{filename}}" width="100%" autoplay="true" loop="false" controller="true" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/"></embed>
                            </object>
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me!! I didn't need the CLASSID or the CODEBASE or the plugins page, but this worked for me on Android. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Should be `autoplay` instead of `autoplay=""` and `controls` instead of `controls=""`. And remove `px`: `width="400" height="300"`

Comment: Sorry, that's actually what I have. Chrome added the ="" to both and I copied and pasted from there. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add `load` on video tag:

```
<video width="400px" height="300px" autoplay controls onklcik="~videoClicked(this)">
    <source src="file:///android_asset/www/video/video-test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

  //somewhere in your scripts
  videoClicked function(elem) {
      $(elem).load();
  }
```

Comment: `onklcik` ? And PS don't use inline JS